# Passing property as parameter in method

Tags: c#

I know the title could probably be a bit more descriptive/better phrased, but it was the best I could come up with.

Currently I have a class with a lot of methods looking like the ones below:

```
        private static void UpdateArtists()
        {
            artists.Clear();
            foreach (AudioInfo entry in library_entries)
            {
                artists.Add(entry.Artist, entry);
            }
        }

        private static void UpdateAlbums()
        {
            albums.Clear();
            foreach (AudioInfo entry in library_entries)
            {
                albums.Add(entry.Album, entry);
            }
        }

        private static void UpdateGenres()
        {
            genres.Clear();
            foreach (AudioInfo entry in library_entries)
            {
                genres.Add(entry.Genre, entry);
            }
        }

        private static void UpdateYears()
        {
            years.Clear();
            foreach (AudioInfo entry in library_entries)
            {
                years.Add(entry.Year, entry);
            }
        }
```

Needless to say, writing dozens of these is very tiresome. So I was wondering if it's possible to simplify it and make a method something like this:

```
     private static void Update(Dictionary<string, AudioInfo> dictionary, AudioInfo.Property property)
     {
         dictionary.Clear();
         foreach (AudioInfo entry in library_entries)
         {
             dictionary.Add(entry.property, entry);
         }
         //Where "property" is a property in the AudioInfo-class.
     }
```

Is that doable, and if it is; how?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that you don't need `ref` at all, classes are always passed by reference.

Comment: Heh, you're right of course. That's what you get when you sit up the entire night.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass a property of a class as a parameter of a method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178574/how-can-i-pass-a-property-of-a-class-as-a-parameter-of-a-method)

Answer (score 15):

It seems like you have some design errors in your class if you need to do such things.
nevertheless, the solution is:

```
private static void Update(Dictionary<string, AudioInfo> dictionary, Func<AudioInfo, string> func)
{
    dictionary.Clear();
    foreach (AudioInfo entry in library_entries)
    {
        dictionary.Add(func(entry), entry);
    }
}
```

And the usage is:

```
Update(years, x => x.Year);
```

Also you can use easier way, instead of call any methods you can just write:

```
years = library_entries.ToDictionary(x => x.Year, x => x);
```

If you have not any events, linked with your dictionary.

And one more thing to go - you can't add different elements with the same keys to dictionary. In your case it seems like you have different `AudioInfo` objects with the same `Year`, `Genre` e.t.c.

Comment: You don't have to pass dictionary by `ref`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just copied the signature from the question.

Comment: Actually I have a custom OneToManyDictionary, that has a list of items for each key. If I add a duplicate key, it adds the value to the list associated with the key. Thought I'd simplify my question and just use a regular Dictionary to avoid more confusion than needed :d. That being said, guess I'll go with the Func version. Thanks!

Comment: I'm genuinely curious what the design errors are in this case.  My code could really benefit from such a critique.  What are the errors and how could they be fixed?