# Is it possible to pass properties as parameters

Tags: c#

If this sounds too impossible, pls dont down vote :) Just my quirk that I wonder if ever I can pass a property as the parameter to a function to get some result.

For eg.

```
void delete_button_click ()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvRecords.SelectedRows)
        dgvRecords.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

And suppose

```
void delete_all_button click ()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvRecords.Rows)
        dgvRecords.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

Can I write the above two codes in one function since the only difference is `SelectedRows` and `Rows`. Something like this:

```
void button_click (/*DataGridView property rows*/)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvRecords.rows)
        dgvRecords.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

And call it

```
{
   button_click(DataGridView.Rows);
   //and
   button_click(DataGridView.SelectedRows);
}
```

Another eg.,

```
decimal GetAmount1(User usr)
{
    decimal sum = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvRecords.Rows)
    {
        Tuple<User, User, Notification, Acknowledgment> tup = (Tuple<User, User, Notification, Acknowledgment>)row.Tag;
        if (tup.Item1 == usr)
            sum += tup.Item4.Sum;

    }
    return sum;
}
```

and

```
decimal GetAmount2(User usr)
{
    decimal sum = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvRecords.Rows)
    {
        Tuple<User, User, Notification, Acknowledgment> tup = (Tuple<User, User, Notification, Acknowledgment>)row.Tag;
        if (tup.Item2 == usr)
            sum += tup.Item4.Sum;

    }
    return sum;
}
```

The only difference in above codes are just a property. So is this available:

```
decimal GetAmount(User usr, Tuple<User, User, Notification, Acknowledgment>.Property Item)
{
    decimal sum = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvRecords.Rows)
    {
        Tuple<User, User, Notification, Acknowledgment> tup = (Tuple<User, User, Notification, Acknowledgment>)row.Tag;
        if (tup.Item == usr)
            sum += tup.Item4.Sum;

    }
    return sum;
}
```

And call :

```
{ 
     GetAmount(usr, Tuple<User, User, Notification, Acknowledgment>.Item1)
     //and
     GetAmount(usr, Tuple<User, User, Notification, Acknowledgment>.Item2)   
}
```

??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass a property of a class as a parameter of a method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178574/how-can-i-pass-a-property-of-a-class-as-a-parameter-of-a-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example is can be solved by just using a normal parameter:

The signature of a method to remove rows would be:

```
void RemoveRows (IList rows)
{
    foreach (var row in rows)
        dgvRecords.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

and call it with:

```
RemoveRows (DataGridView.Rows);
//or
RemoveRows (DataGridView.SelectedRows);
```

The second example requires the use of a [`Func<T, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) which allows you to define what property you want to select.

So your `GetAmount()` method siganture becomes:

```
decimal GetAmount(User usr, Func<Tuple<User, User, Notification, Acknowledgment>, User> selector)
{
    decimal sum = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvRecords.Rows)
    {
        Tuple<User, User, Notification, Acknowledgment> tup = (Tuple<User, User, Notification, Acknowledgment>)row.Tag;
        if (selector(tup) == usr)
            sum += tup.Item4.Sum;

    }
    return sum;
}
```

and you would call it:

```
GetAmount(usr, tuple => tuple.Item1);
//or
GetAmount(usr,  tuple => tuple.Item1);
```

Comment: Terrific! Exactly what I wanted. I think I shouldn't ashamed of posting any crazy question, a solution might still exist in the language :)

Comment: Not at all. My suggestion is to think of the simplest thing first, frequently it's the right way to go :)

Comment: nawfal: woops, thats because `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't have a `.Remove()`. It seems that `IList` defines the `.Remove()` method. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Now how am I supposed to call the method? I tried this: `RemoveRows (dgvRecords.Rows)` which gives compilation error. I tried this: `RemoveRows((IList<DataGridViewRow>)dgvRecords.Rows)` but I get runtime error saying such a cast is not valid.

Comment: @nwfal: hmm, sry. Try my latest update. It seems that the IList is not generic. Try just leaving it as a plain `IList` and by using the `var` keyword, we don't really care what the type of `row` is. Also, what is the compilation error you get?

Comment: What a coincidence, I just got that done exactly now!! Compilation error was something like DataGridViewRowCollection argument doesnt match with IEnumerable<DataGridView>

Comment: In the code, it doesnt matter if it is IEnumerable or IList, Both Works

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a projection to solve the first problem, but for the sake of argument of wanting to select a property, you can pass in a projection to allow the caller to select the property, for example in your first set of methods, you could do.

```
   void DeleteRows(DataGridView dgv, Func<DataGridView, IEnumerable> projection)
   {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in projection(dgv))
            dgv.Rows.Remove(row);
   }
```

Or, alternatively using generics:

```
   void DeleteRows<TCollection>(DataGridView dgv, Func<DataGridView, TCollection> projection) where TCollection : IEnumerable
   {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in projection(dgv))
            dgv.Rows.Remove(row);
   }
```

Then you can call it like:

```
   // delete all rows
   DeleteRows(dgvRecords, d => d.Rows);

   // delete only selected rows
   DeleteRows(dgvRecords, d => d.SelectedRows);
```

That is, in any case where you want to pass in a property dynamically, instead pass in a `Func<...>` that takes in the object and returns the property you want.  This is very similar how LINQ creates such generic algorithms by allowing the caller to specify the projections on which to query the data.

Of course, if you have `public` methods taking in delegates, make sure they are non-`null` before invoking them.  If they're `private` methods under your control, it's not as big of an issue if you control all the calls to them.

**UPDATE** For example 2:

```
decimal GetAmount(User usr, Func<Tuple<User, User, Notification, Acknowledgement>, User> projection)
{
    decimal sum = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvRecords.Rows)
    {
        Tuple<User, User, Notification, Acknowledgment> tup = (Tuple<User, User, Notification, Acknowledgment>)row.Tag;
        if (projection(tup) == usr)
            sum += tup.Item4.Sum;

    }
    return sum;
}
```

And call:

```
GetAmount(user, t => t.Item1);
```

Or

```
GetAmount(user, t => t.Item2);
```

That one's a bit uglier because of the large `Tuple` but still works.

Comment: That's so nice.. What will be the code similarly for the second example in my question? I find it a bit different

Comment: Thanks.. let me mark this as answer since you came up first with an answer.

Comment: This doesn't work. I mean the first example. The reason is `DataGridViewRowCollection` and `DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection` are different

Comment: @nawfal: You can use `IEnumerable` then, all you need to do is be able to iterate over the collection, and both implement `IEnumerable` and both contain `DataGridViewRow`.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @nawfal: Thanks for the heads-up, corrections always welcome!

Comment: :) Your second method using TCollection looks a bit verbose. I dunno the advantage of it though..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with reflection, but I wouldn't recommend it. Here is an example of getting a properties "getter" and working with it:

```
    int someFunction(Element instance, string propertyName)
    {
        MethodInfo prop = typeof(Element).GetProperty(propertyName).GetGetMethod();
        if (prop.ReturnType != typeof(int))
        {
            throw new Exception("Type of property does not match expected type of int");
        }
        return (int)prop.Invoke(instance, null);
    }
```

Again, I would not recommend doing anything like this unless you had a better reason than mentioned above. If you do something like this, you should try hard to cache the MethodInfo object so you don't need to recreate it every time.

Answer (score 0):

This is @Alastair Pitts method, but I change the code a bit to get it working.

```
 void RemoveRows (IEnumerable rows)
 {
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows)
         dgvRecords.Rows.Remove(row);
 }
```

And call it

```
RemoveRows ((IEnumerable)dgvRecords.Rows);
//or
RemoveRows ((IEnumerable)dgvRecords.SelectedRows);
```

I had tried with IEnumerable<> as pointed out by Alastair but it wouldnt work. It's not possible to cast a non-generic to a generic. IEnumerable is in the `System.Collections` namespace and not in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace like IEnumerable<>. Nevertheless, I'm marking his as the answer.