# Params for Generic Collection

Tags: c#, sorting, properties, parameters

I would like to sort a common list in base class from its derived classes.
Each derived class sorts by a different property.

Therefore I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178864/pass-property-itself-to-function-as-parameter-in-c-sharp) idea: pass the relevant property to sort the base-class-list by.

```
protected void SortBy( Func<MyBaseClass, IComparable> getProp)
{
if (BaseClassList != null && BaseClassList .Count > 0)  
 {
  BaseClassList =  BaseClassList 
                  .OrderBy(x => getProp(x))
                  .ToList();
        }

    }
```

And invoke it from derived classes by  `SortBy(x => x.GetTop);`

Well, now I would like to sort by several properties; for each additional sent property, a `ThenBy` expression should be added to the method body.

```
BaseClassList =  BaseClassList 
              .OrderBy(x => getProp(x))  
              .ThenBy(x => x.getOtherProp)
              .ToList();
```

Since I do not know how many properties will be sent I would like to use the  `params` idea.
However, I understand it is impossible since '`The parameter array must be a single dimensional array`'.

Any ideas?

Comment: `params Func<MyBaseClass, IComparable>[] getters`?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, Thanks. Can you show code snippet so I could understand properly what should I change in method body? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
    public static List<T> SortBy<T>(IEnumerable<T> data, Func<T, IComparable> sort, params Func<T, IComparable>[] details )
    {
        var result  =  data.OrderBy(x => sort(x));

        foreach(var detail in details)
        {
            result = result.ThenBy(x => detail(x));
        }

        return result.ToList();
    }
```

Please note that I modified it to work with any list and any datatype. You will have to call it with your `BaseClassList` as first parameter and write the results back again from the return value:

```
BaseClassList = SortBy(BaseClassList, x => x.GetTop, x => x.GetSecondValue, x => x.GetThirdValue);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great! Is there a way to send a notification if to sort by asc or by descending? how? Thanks in advance!