# Why members cannot be accessed by generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, where-clause

I don't understand what am I doing wrong when trying to access members of class from generic type T. I also specifically used WHERE constraint.
I get the following message: 'T' is a type parameter, which is not valid in the current context.

```cs
class Test
{
    public static int id = 1;
    public int GetId()
    {
        return id;
    }
}

public class TestUsage
{
    public int IncrementId<T>() where T : Test
    {
        return 1 + T.GetId();
    }
}
```

Comment: `public int IncrementId<T>(T item) where T : Test { return 1 + item.GetID(); }` T is a type parameter and is used to identify the type of something being used in the generic method. It's not a variable you can use to call methods on.

Comment: `T` is a type. `T.GetId()` is like `String.Length`: *Which* string's length do you want? There are a lot of strings out there.

Comment: `GetId` is not static, so `<type name>.GetId()` doesn't make sense. But even if you made it static, static members cannot be overridden, so you would not refer to `T.GetId()`, you would just say `Test.GetId()`.

Comment: I think you should explain what you're trying to do here. I suspect your design may be based around some misconceptions on how generics in C# work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in `public int IncrementId<T>(T test)` the type parameter `T` could just be any type, C# has no clue which members this type has. You can add a generic type constraint. A way to do this, is to define an interface that types must implement to be used as type argument.

```
public interface IHasId
{
    int GetId();
}

class Test : IHasId
{
    public static int id = 1;
    public int GetId()
    {
        return id;
    }
}

public int IncrementId<T>(T item) where T : IHasId
{
    return item.GetId() + 1;
}
```

---

Another option is to pass a property accessor to the method

```
public int IncrementId<T>(T item, Func<T, int> getId)
{
    return getId(item) + 1;
}
```

You would call it with

```
int nextId = IncrementId(test, t => t.GetId());
```

See also:

- [Pass property itself to function as parameter in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178864/pass-property-itself-to-function-as-parameter-in-c-sharp)
- My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9854944/880990) to the question [How can I find a specific element in a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854917/how-can-i-find-a-specific-element-in-a-listt) explains that you should not use a method `GetId` but instead should use a property in C#.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Olivier-Jacot-Descombes I changed the GetId to be a property

Answer (score 1):

Declaring the method as generic means that you can pass an argument of the generic type. So you could do this:

```
public class TestUsage
{
    public int IncrementId<T>(T test) where T : Test
    {
        return 1 + test.GetId();
    }
}
```

The generic type argument `T` doesn't mean anything unless something with that type is used either as an input argument, a return value, a variable of type `T` within the method, or some combination.

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide an instance of T. Try:

```
public int IncrementId<T>(T t) where T : Test
{
    return 1 + t.GetId();
}
```