# How to generic pass class as parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class Skeleton : Monster
{
    private MonsterBaseState state;
    private void Awake()
    {
        state = new PatrolState<Skeleton>(this);
    }
    public void  GetMonsterInfo()
    {
      dosomething;
    }
}
pubilc class ManyMonster:Monster 
{
    private MonsterBaseState state;
    private void Awake()
    {
        state = new PatrolState<Skeleton>(this);
    }
}
//and more monster Class

public interface MonsterBaseState
{
    void BehaviorForUpdate();
}
public class PatrolState<T> : MonsterBaseState
{ 
    private T cluster;
    public PatrolState(T curCluster)
    {
        cluster = curCluster;
        cluster.GetMonsterInfo();//wrong here
    }
        public void BehaviorForUpdate()
    {
    }
}
```

I can't use the GetMonsterinfo method in the PatrolState Class

I want to pass the skeleton or other monster ， so I don't have to write a lot of status code

Comment: `public class PatrolState<T> : MonsterBaseState where T:Skeleton `

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56449035/why-members-cannot-be-accessed-by-generic-type

Comment: Rather have a common base **class** which already implents the core members and behavior instead of inheriting from `MonoBehaviour` everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement interface IMonster as below:

```
public interface IMonster
{
    void GetMonsterInfo();
    //void MonsterMethod1();
    //void MonsterMethod2();
    //..
}

public class Skeleton : MonoBehaviour, IMonster
{
    private MonsterBaseState state;
    private void Awake()
    {
        state = new PatrolState<Skeleton>(this);
    }
    public void GetMonsterInfo()
    {
    }
}

public interface MonsterBaseState
{
    void BehaviorForUpdate();
}

public class PatrolState<T> : MonsterBaseState where T :IMonster
{ 
    private T cluster;
    public PatrolState(T curCluster)
    {
        cluster = curCluster;
        cluster.GetMonsterInfo();//wrong here
    }
    
    public void BehaviorForUpdate()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I use lots of skeleton.method() in PatrolState Class,It means implement many interfaces？

Comment: @KDYG Just need only one interface IMonster, and extend it.

Comment: @derHugo I'm sorry,  I didn't notice that where using new on MonoBehaviour.

Comment: Oh no sorry about that .. just noted they actually don't ^^ my bad