# Pass object property as parameter and access it

Tags: c#, properties, filtering

I have looked through all SO answers to this question but haven't found a single appealing answer. I am trying to create a TextFilter class for generating simple observable collection filters for string based properties. Here is what I have in mind:

```
public class TextFilter : IFilter
{
   Func<string> Property;
   string Target { get; set; }

   public TextFilter(Func<string>property, string target)
   {
      Property = property;
      Target = target;
   }

   public bool Filter(object item)
   {
      return ((MyObject)item).***Property***.Contains(Target);
    }
}
```

However I cannot find a way to pass my properties and access them afterwards?

Comment: Can you please explain how standard delegate solutions you've seen does not work for your case - like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178574/how-can-i-pass-a-property-of-a-class-as-a-parameter-of-a-method

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov That is actually what I have been looking for, I just didn't realize at first, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
public class TextFilter : IFilter
{
   Func<object, string> Property;
   string Target { get; set; }

   public TextFilter(Func<object, string> property, string target)
   {
      Property = property;
      Target = target;
   }

   public bool Filter(object item)
   {
      return Property(item).Contains(Target);
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
var value = new MyObject() { Property = "This is a Test" };

var filter = new TextFilter(o => ((MyObject)o).Property, "Test");

bool isFiltered = filter.Filter(value);
```

If you don't need your TextFilters to be the same class, you could use a generic `TextFilter<T>` instead of using `object`.

If you really want to have properties only, you may need [expression trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb397951.aspx).

Comment: Could you give a sample TextFilter instantiation?