# Passing a property by reference into a method (same name, different classes)

Tags: c#

```
public class Address
{...}

public class Object1
{
   public Address Address {get;set;}
}

public class Object2
{
   public Address Address {get;set;}
}

public UpdateAddress(Address address)
{
   address = new Address();
}

//calling
var obj1 = new Object1();
UpdateAddress(obj1.Address);
```

//obj1.Address IS NULL

I cannot have my 2 classes inherit from a baseclass that has Address property (long story)

I was under the impression that when passing objects into methods they are by reference and my obj1.Address will have a new one and not be null if i am passing that property into a method.

If my assumption is wrong and it seems to be about object not being passed by reference in this instance.

How can i have a generic method that I can update a property that is the same across all my objects (I know I can return a new address object but I prefer to be passed in instead of returning)

Can this also be done by passing T<>?

**UPDATE - Actual Code**

Calling the methods

```
bool isVendorIdFromModel = UpdateVendor(entity.ExpenseVendor, entity.ExpenseVendorId, model, isNew, context);
if (isVendorIdFromModel)
{
    entity.ExpenseVendorId = model.VendorId;
}

private static bool UpdateVendor(ExpenseVendor vendor, int? entityVendorId, ExpenseBaseModel model, bool isNew, ELMSContext context)
    {
        if (model.VendorId.HasValue)
        {
            if (entityVendorId != model.VendorId)
            {
                return true;
            }
            UpdateVendorInfo(model, vendor);

        }
        else
        {
            if (isNew && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.VendorName))
            {
                vendor = new ExpenseVendor
                {
                    ...
                };
                context.ExpenseVendors.Add(vendor); 

            }
            if (vendor != null)
            {
                UpdateVendorInfo(model, vendor);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    private static void UpdateVendorInfo(ExpenseBaseModel model, ExpenseVendor vendor)
    {
        vendor.Name = model.VendorName;
        vendor.Address1 = model.Address1;
        vendor.Address2 = model.Address2;
        vendor.City = model.City;
        vendor.PostalCode = model.PostalCode?.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        vendor.ProvinceId = model.ProvinceId;
    }
```

Comment: Can both classes implement from same interface? Refer this article from Jon http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html to have a good understanding about parameter passing.

Comment: "I was under the impression that when passing objects into methods they are by reference". No, they aren't. Objects aren't passed at all. References are passed, by value. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: @SriramSakthivel unfortunately they cannot, these are entity framework classes and Address is a shared table, which becomes a property of each of the entities

Comment: Almost duplicate with deleted answer by Jon Skeet using lambdas... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178574/how-can-i-pass-a-property-of-a-class-as-a-parameter-of-a-method

Answer (score 2):

Usual options:

- shared base class (if you can change code and class hierarchy)
- shared interface (if you can can change code, but no class hierarchy)
- pass lambdas for getter/setter
- use reflection and set by name

Since it sounds like you can't change the source lambda option may be the easiest. Following is option to "set" (when you replace whole object):

```
public void UpdateAddress(Action<Address> addressSetter)
{
   addressSetter(new Address());
}

//calling
var obj1 = new Object1();
UpdateAddress(address => obj1.Address = address);
```

If you need to set properties of such object instead of replacing - pass `get` delegate:

```
public void UpdateAddress(Func<Address> addressGetter)
{
   addressGetter().Street = "Dark alley";
}
UpdateAddress(address => obj1.Address);
```

Or use both. You can even combine them into helper class so it look close to properties (check out [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Note: generics not going to help you unless you can add common interface (but in that case you probably don't need generics at all).

Comment: @Zoinky I assume you wanted to just change *some* properties of "Address"? (see updated)... Not sure what "why returning an int." relates to.

Comment: The just of what I am trying to do is if record is new then either they selected a vendor (Vendorid being filled) or the other properties come from the model such as name address etc.  If however t he record is an update then make sure to update the address components from the fields.  All in all I need to re-evaluate my strategy of setting the vendor because the code is getting to be confusing

Answer (score 0):

If `UpdateAddress` only returns an address then change it to:

```
public Address UpdateAddress()
{
    // set up address
    return address;
}


var obj1 = new Object1();
obj1.Address = UpdateAddress();
```

Passing by reference and manipulating the contents of a parameter is a code smell. Write methods that return values and set the property that way.

Comment: The method already returns a int (not showing in the example), but I guess I can change it so that the return is more generic.  I was trying to avoid returning objects, might have to do this anyways

Comment: @Zoinky, what's the purpose of that int? You are trying to return an Address via "the back door" by trying to treat it as a ref.